# How to handle exceptions in enduser friendly way

Tags: android

I am developing an android app where I am dealing with sending and receiving information to and from our servers.Please let me know when any sort of exception occurs I am trying to show an alertbox, but **the issue is that the alert box is not  displayed always**. Please help me with a solution so that when ever an exception takes place some sort of friendly UI is to be displayed.
The AlertBox I am using

```
public  void Alertbox(String title, String mymessage,Context context ) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    .setMessage(mymessage)

    .setCancelable(true)
    .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()

    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int whichButton) {



        }
    }).show();
}

public static void ProcessDialogue(String title,Context context)
{


}
```

Comment: Is the alert box not displayed intentionally or you just didn't catch all exceptions?

Comment: It is unable to call all the exceptions

Comment: I think Yahor10 has answered your question. Besides, there might be error you wouldn't like to show the user. Consider other ways of handling exceptions along with error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create ErrorBroadcastReceiver and Error ACTION with Extras string.

```
public class ErrorReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String ERROR_ACTION = "com.yourpackage.ERROR_ACTION";
    public static final String ERROR_MESSAGE = "ERROR_MESSAGE"; 

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String errorMessage = intent.getStringExtra(ERROR_MESSAGE);     
        Toast.makeText(context, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

and send broadcast intents to this receiver

```
 Intent errorIntent = new Intent(ERROR_ACTION);
        errorIntent.putExtra(ERROR_MESSAGE , e.getMessage());// exception from try/catch block or your custom error type
        sendBroadcast(errorIntent)
```

Comment: I suppose this part will show errors during sending& receiving the data. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What value do I set to intent ?